# Manipulating the definition of $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I manipulated the standard definition of $\sigma$ algebra generated by a family of sets $\mathcal{A}$,

$$
\sigma ( \mathcal{A}) := \bigcap \{ \Sigma \ | \ \Sigma \text{ is a $\sigma$-algebra on } X, \mathcal{A} \subseteq \Sigma \},
$$
and I came up with the following:
$$
\sigma ( \mathcal{A}) := \{A \ | \ \forall \ \Sigma \text{ $\sigma$-algebra on $X$} \ (\mathcal{A} \subseteq \Sigma \Rightarrow A \in \Sigma ) \}.
$$

Are the two equal?
In particular, I have some doubts regarding the implication in the second definition (I always have problems in dealing with these kind of expressions).

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

*PS: I did put the elementary set theory tag, because in my opinion the question is more concerned with the way in which expressions with the bigcap should be handled, than measure theory.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, you really just applied the definition of $\bigcap$. Recall the definition:

$$\bigcap\{A_i\mid i\in I\}=\{X\mid\forall i\in I: X\in A_i\}.$$

So the intersection of all the $\sigma$-algebras which include $\mathcal A$ is all the sets which appear in every $\sigma$-algebra which include $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. My doubt was really with the implication. Would it be wrong if I would have written $\sigma ( \mathcal{A}) := \{A \ | \ \forall \ \Sigma \text{ $\sigma$-algebra on $X$} \ ( A \in \Sigma \Rightarrow \mathcal{A} \subseteq \Sigma ) \}$? Are they actually different? They should, right? _This was my big doubt, and where I find a bit problematic the application of the definition._

Comment: Well, $\varnothing$ is in every $\sigma$-algebra, but $\mathcal A$ doesn't have to be included in every $\sigma$-algebra. So $\varnothing$ won't satisfy the definition you propose in the comment, and therefore the result is not a $\sigma$-algebra at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quite insightful!